# Implementing a simple ring buffer for float values

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a very simple ring buffer, for holding a stream of audio samples in the form of float values.

I want to be able to take a snapshot of the audio input at any one time. I don't need to pop or delete any values, just keep a moving buffer of the last *n* samples.

I'd like to ask if there are any potential issues with this implementation for my purposes.

```
class RingBuffer
{
public:
    RingBuffer (int bufferSize) : bufferSize (bufferSize), count (0), head (0)
    {
        buffer     = static_cast<float *> (malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(float)));
        readBuffer = static_cast<float *> (malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(float)));
    }

    ~RingBuffer ()
    {
        if (buffer != nullptr) free(buffer);
        buffer = nullptr;

        if (readBuffer != nullptr) free(readBuffer);
        readBuffer = nullptr;
    }

    void push (float value)
    {

        if (count < bufferSize && head == 0)
        {
            buffer[count++] = value;
        }
        else if (count == bufferSize)
        {
            // reset head to beginning if reached the end
            if (head >= bufferSize)
            {
                head = 0;
                buffer[head] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                buffer[head++] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return a snapshot of the buffer as a continous array
     */
    const float* getSnapshot () 
    {
         // Set up read buffer as continuous stream
         int writeIndex = 0;
         for (int i = head; i < count; ++i) 
         {
            readBuffer[writeIndex++] = buffer[i];   
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < head; ++i)
         {
             readBuffer[writeIndex++] = buffer[i];
         }
         return readBuffer;
    }

private:
    int bufferSize, head, count;
    float* buffer;
    float* readBuffer;
};
```

Comment: This is off topic for here and should probably be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As this is C++ you might be persuaded to used `new` and `delete` in place of `malloc` and `free`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are indeed several issues I can see. Sorry for the bad news :-/

*Bugs*

- There is a bug here: `buffer[head] = value;`. You don't increment `head`, so the sample at this position will be lost (overwritten) when the next sample comes in.
- In the constructor, you should initialize `buffer` and `readBuffer` to `nullptr`: if one of your mallocs failed, your destructor would try to free
- Your 1st loop in `getSnapshot` is faulty: the end-point should be `min(bufferSize,head+count)` rather than `count`

*Design issues*

- As pointed out by mathematician1975, you should allocate your arrays with `new float[bufferSize]`, it's simpler and more readable than mallocs
- You should hold each buffer using a `std::unique_ptr`, so that you would no longer need any destructor (and your code would be much safer)
- As you are working on circular buffers, you should use modulo arithmetics, e.g. `writeIndex = (writeIndex +1 ) % bufferSize`. Your code will be much simpler that way, especially in getSnapshot (one loop instead of two)

Comment: No bad news. Thank you for your thorough answer. The first bug you spotted should have been obvious (!), and the rest was informative and helping me to understand how to tackle this problem better.